# Is it common to caulk around the edges of vinyl tile instead of going underneath wood paneling?

Tags: flooring, kitchens, caulking

I have a guy going into a rental unit of mine to put in vinyl tile. I told him specifically that I wanted it under the base of the wall's wood molding ([similiar to this stuff](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Zamma-Recoatable-White-5-8-in-Height-x-3-4-in-Wide-x-94-in-Length-Laminate-Quarter-Round-Molding-013140324/203204367)).

He was put off by this idea. Told me he wanted to use caulk instead and that it was a better option. I insisted because I thought he was corner cutting and he went under the molding like I had requested.

My question is though, now after researching this. It doesn't appear to be that much of a cut corner as I originally took it.

Is it common practice to caulk around the edges of vinyl tile in a kitchen instead of going underneath wood paneling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caulking from vinyl to quarter round isn't a very long-term solution.  The quarter round is small and flexible, the area is dirty, it sees a lot of traffic, it gets dirty.  The caulk will fail within a year or two of use and have to be scraped and redone.  Putting the flooring under the quarter round with no caulk is a much better solution.

Comment: Okay thank you. I am happy I insisted on this option then